# what is: { name: "Taylor" } in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Could someone, please, tel me what is the : {name : "Taylor"} in the code below:

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(HelloMessage, { name: "Taylor" }),
document.getElementById('hello-example'));
```

Comment: `{ name: "Taylor" }` is an object that is passed to HelloMessage. I'm guessing the HelloMessage contains some code that says: `Hello ${name}`. So, the name get's replaced with Taylor and the output is 'Hello Taylor`.

Answer (score 2):

It passes the object `{ name: "Taylor" }` into the `props` object for the `HelloMessage` component.

As a result, inside the `HelloMessage` component, `props.name` will equal **"Taylor"**.

For more info see here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html

Answer (score 1):

It is an object in JavaScript. Read about objects in JS:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp